# NODE Js, local host, error "throw err"

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, localhost, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Bluemix to make a web service for a school project.

I am having trouble running my app in the local host.

> Throw err
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'

I can't figure out what is wrong.

Here is a print of the error screen I get when running it.

[image: error]

Comment: Do you have it in your `package.json`? Sounds like it is probably not present in your `node_modules` folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you are saying I assume that your application is running fine on Bluemix. Use the CLI of your machine to navigate into the application folder (where the package.json is placed) and run

```
npm install
```

it will download all the dependencies listed in the package.json in the node_modules folder inside your application root folder.

Doing this your application will have all the libraries it needs to run.